# cc1plus.exe gets stuck when CI build is cancelled

Tags: gcc, cmake, azure-devops, vxworks, ninja

I frequently get errors like

```
warning: failed to remove Build/x86-vxworks-kernel-gcc-Release-Ninja: Permission denied
```

in my CI build. Investigating the build server, I see it is always cc1plus.exe stuck in this folder. From the comand line of cc1plus.exe I can see, its a (random) cpp file being translated. I guess the real compiler I call in CMake (c++pentium.exe) redirects to this executable.

I am pretty sure (although I cannot prove it) this occurs on servers when builds are canceled. The error message does not come from cancelled build, it comes from custom pre-build clean steps of the following builds.
I do net recall getting this locally. Maybe it is related to how the CI is stopping the Build?

Setup:

- Azure DevOps Server (on premise)
- CMake + Ninja
- VxWorks 6.8 GCC compiler (4.1.2) (I think its based on mingw)

Have you seen similar issues? Any general tips where I could further investigate?

Can i configure the build (yaml) to not cancel steps but wait till they finish or timeout? I guess this would also fix it with fairly low overhead in build time.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i configure the build (yaml) to not cancel steps but wait till they finish or timeout? I guess this would also fix it with fairly low overhead in build time.

As workaround, we could set the **Even if a previous task has failed, even if the build was canceled** on the `Control Options` for ninja task/step:

[image]

Check the document [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some details.

Note: Don't forget to set Timeout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am already in that github issue if you read closely :). However, no, the error message does not come from Ninja, it comes from custom pre-build clean steps of the following build.

Comment: @kuga, Thanks for you reply and update. So, this issue should comes from custom pre-build clean steps? If yes, so what is your problem now? Does the workaround in the answer work for you?

Comment: I did not try it, since I think your solution does not fit. (Maybe I dont get it...). On which step should I set this?
Of course I could ignore this error, but then, the folder would not be cleaned.
What I want is a solution, so the cancelling does not leave processes dangling around.

Comment: @kuga, Set this on the step, which have custom pre-build clean steps. In this case, this step will keep running after you cancelled the build until the steps complete or timeout.

Comment: That would not help. The executable does not get stuck in the cleanup steps. The cleanup step simply fails.
I could set it on the steps that cause the stuck process, however I doubt this ensures that they are never cancelled. Also it is not practical since that are nearly all steps and this would highly increase build time.